# Using a split with a regex not replacing correctly?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse rows of text in order to retrive the 4 version numbers:

```
v.1.7.600.0 - latest | 9.2.6200.0 to 9.2.9999
```

I'm looking to be able to parse a line like this into:

```
['v.1.7.600.0', 'latest', '9.2.6200.0', '9.2.9999']
```

At the moment, I have something like this:

```js
var line = "v.1.7.600.0 - latest | 9.2.6200.0 to 9.2.9999"
var result = line.split(/ (\||-|to) /g)
console.log(result)
```

I'm not that great at regex but it matches so i'm not sure why it includes them in the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there, just use  a non-capturing group:

```js
var line = "v.1.7.600.0 - latest | 9.2.6200.0 to 9.2.9999";
var result = line.split(/\s+(?:\||-|to)\s+/);
console.log(result);
```

You need a *non-capturing group* because `split()` will extract captured values into the resulting array.

Also, it might be more convenient to match one or more whitespaces with `\s+` rather than using a literal space.

Besides, the `/g` modifier is redundant with `split()`, it the default behavior.

You also may define a character class for single char delimiters, and write a bit more compact `/\s+(?:[|-]|to)\s+/` regex.